# What is the best way of arranging multiple minipages on a page?

Tags: graphics, typography, minipage

I have been trying to use mini-pages to produce the equivalent of Office text-boxes. The idea is to have panels of different sizes on a page such as 4 equal sized or one wide followed by two long boxes.

I have one fairly clunky solution below. Is there a better way of doing this so I can be more flexible. For example is there any way I can specify the height of a mini-page in inches, cm or pts?

Thanks

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}             
\usepackage{microtype}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{wallpaper} 
\ULCornerWallPaper{1.0}{/Users/tahnoon/Dropbox/Projects/ai_ppt.pdf} \topmargin=0.25in \headheight=1in \headsep=0.1in 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\null
\vspace{-3cm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.4cm}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.35\paperwidth} p{0.35\paperwidth}}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t][0.35\paperheight]{0.35\paperwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}}
&
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][0.35\paperheight]{0.35\paperwidth}
\lipsum[4]
\end{minipage}}  \\
&\\
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][0.35\paperheight]{0.35\paperwidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}} &
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][0.35\paperheight]{0.35\paperwidth}
\lipsum[3]
\end{minipage} }\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape]{article}
%\usepackage{geometry} %
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=2.2in, right=0.75in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\ULCornerWallPaper{1.1}{ai_ppt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[c][\dimexpr 0.495\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax][t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}%
}%
\vfill
\noindent
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[l][\dimexpr 0.495\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax][t]{\dimexpr 0.495\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}%
    \lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}%
}%
\hfill
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[r][\dimexpr 0.495\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax][t]{\dimexpr 0.495\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}%
    \lipsum[4]
\end{minipage}%
}%
%
\newpage
%
\noindent
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[l][\dimexpr\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax][t]{\dimexpr .495\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}%
}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[r][\textheight][t]{.495\textwidth}
    \noindent\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[c][\dimexpr 0.49\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax][t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxsep\relax}%
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{minipage}
    }
    \vfill
    \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[c][\dimexpr 0.49\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax][t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxsep\relax}%
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{minipage}
    }
\end{minipage}%
%
\newpage
%
\noindent
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[l][\dimexpr.495\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax][t]{\dimexpr .495\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}%
}%
\hfill
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[r][\dimexpr 0.495\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax][t]{\dimexpr .495\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}%
    \lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}%
}%
\vfill
\noindent
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[l][\dimexpr 0.495\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax][t]{\dimexpr .495\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}%
    \lipsum[4]
\end{minipage}%
}%
\hfill
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[r][\dimexpr 0.495\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax][t]{\dimexpr .495\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}%
    \lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}%
}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect @Harish. Would you mind explaining what the code is doing? It would really help me replicate it. I'm especially curious about the \dimexpr and the \vfil & \hfill commands. Thanks

Comment: @TahnoonPasha: `\dimexpr` allows you to do arithmatic on dimensions. `\vfill` and `\vfil` are hard and soft ways to push things to the bottom of the page and same for `\hfill` and `\hfil` but to the right end (horizontally). I have specified both the width and height for the minipages along with their positions and text position inside the minipages.

Answer (score 3):

You can do all that is in Harish Kumar's solution more compactly in a loop.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in,left=2in,right=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x/\y/\z/\p/\q in {.48/.937/l/1/\vfil, .48/.45/l/1/\hfil,
  .48/.45/r/1/\newpage, 1/.45/l/1/\hfill,1/.5/r/1/\newpage}{%
  \noindent\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[\z][\dimexpr\x\textheight-2\fboxsep\relax]
      [t]{\dimexpr\y\textwidth\relax}%
    \lipsum[\p]
    \end{minipage}%
  }\q
}
\end{document}
```