# Split a beamer frame in four equal parts

Tags: beamer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way of arranging multiple minipages on a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69560/what-is-the-best-way-of-arranging-multiple-minipages-on-a-page)

I want to split a beamer frame in four equal parts. Each of these parts will have a border around it and will contain different things (itemized list in one part, a table in another, an image in the third, etc.)

I should be able to control vertical and horizontal alignment of content in each part, e.g. Itemized list should be top and left aligned, table should be center aligned vertically and horizontally, etc.

I thought of using columns. But could not get what I wanted.

Can what I am aiming at be achieved? How?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,english,professionalfonts,smaller,handout]{beamer}                                                                                 

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme[named=Black]{structure}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Slide1}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item   One 
                \item   Two 
            \end{itemize}
            \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l l}
                A & B \\ \midrule
                A & B \\ \midrule
                A & B \\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular*}
        \end{column}

        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item   One 
                \item   Two 
            \end{itemize}
            \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l l}
                A & B \\ \midrule
                A & B \\ \midrule
                A & B \\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular*}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I could split into two columns but I am unable to get the control on placement I need.

Comment: show what you tried and post the code here.

Comment: Perhaps `minipage`s.

Comment: The answer below is pretty similar and worked very well for me [Best way of arranging multiple minipages on a page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69560/what-is-the-best-way-of-arranging-multiple-minipages-on-a-page) I was looking for a similar outcome, 4 sub pages on a single minipage.

Comment: One question. The comment above answers my question. How do I mark my question as 'Answered'?